# Getting parent class member from child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

The code below works as expected.

From classes **B** and **C** I'm able to access **m_value** declared in class **D** using the virtual method **get_value()**.

```
    class A_abstract
    {
    protected:
      [[nodiscard]] virtual int get_value() const noexcept = 0;
    };
    
    class B: A_abstract
    {
    protected:
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_B1() const noexcept { return get_value(); }
    public:
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_B2() const noexcept { return get_value(); }
    };
    
    class C: A_abstract
    {
    protected:
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_C1() const noexcept { return get_value(); }
    public:
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_C2() const noexcept { return get_value(); }
    };
    
    class D: public B, public C
    {
    protected:
      int m_value = 10;
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value() const noexcept override { return m_value; }
    public:
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_1() const noexcept { return m_value; }
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_2() const noexcept { return get_value(); }
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_3() const noexcept { return get_value_B1(); }
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_4() const noexcept { return get_value_C1(); }
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_5() const noexcept { return get_value_B2(); }
      [[nodiscard]] int get_value_6() const noexcept { return get_value_C2(); }
    };
    
    int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
    {
    
      D instance;
    
      std::cout << "get_value_1() = " << instance.get_value_1() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_2() = " << instance.get_value_2() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_3() = " << instance.get_value_3() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_4() = " << instance.get_value_4() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_5() = " << instance.get_value_5() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_6() = " << instance.get_value_6() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_B2() = " << instance.get_value_B2() << '\n';
      std::cout << "get_value_C2() = " << instance.get_value_C2() << '\n';
    
    }
```

Output:

```
get_value_1() = 10
get_value_2() = 10
get_value_3() = 10
get_value_4() = 10
get_value_5() = 10
get_value_6() = 10
get_value_B2() = 10
get_value_C2() = 10
```

But is this implementation ok from best practices point of view?

What is the common pattern for this kind of calls? I mean calls of the parent method (**get_value** from **D** class), to get a parent property value (**m_value**) from a child class (**A** and **B**)?

Comment: This lacks context, and it's hard to determine from your example what it's an example of. What problem is it supposed to solve, and what exactly is "this kind of calls"?

Comment: @molbdnilo Added some clarification. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello @canonier, is this still an issue for you? If yes, than I am going to help you. Before, I can help you, I need some more details. I have the following questions:
1) Why did you derive `class B: A_abstract` but `class D: public B, public C`?
2) Why do you have a protected and a public version to access the same function?
3) What is your _use case_ and/or purpose to access a member of `class D` via class D -> cass B/C -> class A -> class D?
I might make sense, but in your example it doesn't.